# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In the following code I'm attempting to find an object using parse. When I print the object WITH commenting out `self.names.append((object["username"] as? String)!)`, I get the object with the username (the attribute I want).

When I print the object WITHOUT commenting out `self.names.append((object["username"] as? String)!)`, I DO get exactly the same object, but WITHOUT the username (the attribute I want).

I do exactly the same thing with `self.comments.append((object["Comment"] as? String)!)` but that does work.
I am positive that I didn't make any spelling mistakes, including capitalisation. (Comment is with a capital and username is not)

```
var comments = [String()]
var names = [String()]
var images = [UIImage()]
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                print(object)


                self.comments.append((object["Comment"] as? String)!)
                self.names.append((object["username"] as? String)!)     < Error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
                self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)



                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize all arrays this way:

```
var comments = [String]()
var names = [String]()
var images = [UIImage]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
```

If the `username` key could be missing you have to check it. With this code it appends `n/a` if the key is missing.

```
self.names.append((object["username"] as? String) ?? "n/a")
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference :(

Comment: Is `object` printed out properly?

Comment: It is when I comment out "self.names.append((object["username"] as? String)!)", but it is not when I have it in my code..